# Verifying that a multidimensional array contains a pair of values

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am making a signin form for a webpage. I have created a multidimensional array with acceptable username/password combinations. I would like to allow the user to move on to the next page only if their username/password combination is found in the array. If they enter a combination that is not found in the array, I want an error to raise and keep them from proceeding to the next page.

I understand that this is not the most effective way to complete this command, but I am learning how to properly use Arrays as part of the foundation to my programming knowledge. I'll paste my code below. I've tried various way to get the page to do what I want, but I can't seem to get it. I get this error: "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array." Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">
    string[,] UserPass = new string[,] {{"user1","pwd1"}, {"user2", "pwd2"}, {"user3","pwd3"}};


void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        

    }

    void btnSignin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(txtSignin.Text == UserPass[1,0] && txtPWD.Text == UserPass[0,1])
         {
             Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
         }

         else if (txtSignin.Text == UserPass[2, 0] && txtPWD.Text == UserPass[0, 2])
         {
             Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
         }

         else if (txtSignin.Text == UserPass[3, 0] && txtPWD.Text == UserPass[0, 3])
         {
             Response.Redirect("welcome.aspx");
         }

         else 
         {
             Response.Write("Please try again."); 
         }
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <p>Sign in with Account</p>
        <asp:Panel ID="Pnl1" runat="server">
            <br />
            <asp:Textbox ID="txtSignin" runat="server" Text="Username" style="width:190px" /><br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPWD" runat="server" Text="Password" TextMode="Password" style="width:190px" /><br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSignin" runat="server" Text="Sign in" class="myBtn" OnClick="btnSignin_Click"/><br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemember" runat="server" Text="Stay signed in" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSignin" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

(also, on a smaller note, is it possible to have the signin/password boxes display text that disappears when the users clicks the textbox?)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: "(also, on a smaller note, is it possible to have the signin/password boxes display text that disappears when the users clicks the textbox?)" This is called a placeholder. You can do this with the placeholder attribute on the element . If you use IE, I believe it only works on version 9 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different options. One is using arrays with a for loop and another is using Linq. I will show you how to do it with arrays.

```
   string[,] UserPass = new string[,] {{"user1","pwd1"}, {"user2.edu", "pwd2"}, {"user3","pwd3"}};
   ...
    bool isFound = false;
    for (int i=0;  i< UserPass.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        //search users row by row
        if (UserPass[i, 0] == yourSearchUserid && UserPass[i, 1] == yourSearchPassword)
        {
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }   
    }
    //isFound holds the search result.
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. However, I'm wondering what the logic behind it is. I'm not sure why that for statement was able to work. What did finding the GetLength property do? I'm new to all this. Thanks again.

Comment: Your array has 3rows &2 cols. A cell can be identified (and have its value manipulated) given the row and the column values of the cell. The for loop is examining the rows sequentially one row at a time until no more rows. The if statement is checking whether the first cell in the current row = the userid AND whether the second cell in the current row = the password value. A cell is generally referred to as UserPass[i,j]. In this example we vary i from 0 to the last row (obtained by Getlength(0)), 0 is used because the rows represent the 1st dimension. The topic is detailed in the net.